# Delphi Upload file to FTP

Tags: delphi, text, ftp

I just created this little app that dumps 2 strings into txt file. Now i want that txt file to be uploaded to ftp. I've looked some tutorials but can't find any good one on how to do it. Please help me. I'll post my code for file.

```
   var

  fText:textfile;
  sText:string;
  s1Text:string;
begin
assignfile(fText,'d:\test.txt') ;

if fileExists('d:\test.txt') <>true then
begin

  rewrite(fText);
  end

  else
  begin
  Append(fText)
  end;


  sText:=Edit1.Text;
  s1Text:=Edit2.Text;
  writeln(fText,sText) ;
  writeln(fText,s1Text);
  closefile(fText);
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it, is via a Windows FTP command called from within your Delphi code using `CreateProcess`. To make it easy to expand the functionality to upload more files, I am using an uploadscript that tells the Windows FTP command what to do. (A similar function will work to download files: Start by changing the `put` to a `get`)

```
function TForm1.Upload: Boolean;
var
  Script: TStringList;
  Command: String;
begin

    Script := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Script.Text := 'User Username' + #13#10 +
      'Password' + #13#10 +
      'cd /temp' + #13#10 + // ftp folder (destination)
      'put d:\test.txt' + #13#10 + // local folder (source)
      'bye';
      Script.SaveToFile('d:\test\myuploadscript.txt');

      Command := 'FTP -v -i -n -s:"d:\test\myuploadscript.txt" ftp://mytestftpsite'

      Result := ExecNewProcess(Command, True);

   finally
     Script.Free;
   end;

end;

function TForm1.ExecNewProcess(ProgramName: String; AShowMsg: Boolean): Longword;
var
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  CreateOK: Boolean;
begin

  FillChar(StartInfo,SizeOf(TStartupInfo),#0);
  FillChar(ProcInfo,SizeOf(TProcessInformation),#0);
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  if AShowMsg then
  begin
    StartInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    StartInfo.wShowWindow := SW_SHOW;
  end;

  CreateOK := CreateProcess(nil, @ProgramName[1], nil, nil, False,
              NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
              nil, nil, StartInfo, ProcInfo);

  if CreateOK then
  begin
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeProcess(ProcInfo.hProcess, Result);
  end;

  if ProcInfo.hProcess <> 0 then
    CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hProcess);
  if ProcInfo.hThread <> 0 then
    CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hThread);
end;
```

Comment: This is a terrible answer. Delphi comes with a perfectly good set of internet components (Indy) that supports FTP, and there are other native solutions available as well. Spawning a command-line utility to do something you can do natively (in fewer lines of code) is simply wrong.

Comment: It's still works though.

Comment: @Ken White Note, in my answer I said "One way to do it". I made no claim to it being the shortest, simplest, easiest or best answer. It is however, a complete answer to the question. As such, it can't be "wrong" - it's just one you don't happen to like!

Comment: Didn't say it was wrong. I said it's a terrible answer. It's like being asked how best to move 1000 chimney bricks and answering *Rent a Porsche and move 100 loads of 10 bricks each* rather than *Rent a truck*.

Comment: I see the words "is simply wrong" in your first comment above. Nevertheless, if I choose to move bricks 10 at a time using a Porsche, then why can't I? Will the brick-moving police slap me with a fine!?

Comment: I'm not debating this with you. See the approximately 5 lines of code in the duplicate question I linked, compared with the ridiculous number of lines (and increased complexity) of  code you posted. If you have the option of using a truck or a Porsche to move bricks, and you choose the Porsche, it doesn't demonstrate a lot of common sense. No one here is impressed that you can write dozens of lines of unnecessary code to reinvent the wheel (and do so in an extremely inefficient manner in the process).

Comment: The only reason the Indy version _appears_ simpler is because the complexity is in the underlying library, instead of in the calling code. My code illustrates several possibilities, and doesn't _just_ answer the question. That's useful,  even though if **you** think it's wrong, inefficient or terrible.

Comment: That's just nonsense. Using `CreateProcess` hides the underlying complexity of setting up registers and launching an application, too. By your logic, that should be eliminated as well and you should write it in pure assembly (which you can then further reduce to pure opcodes). Knock yourself out. Reinventing the wheel needlessly is seldom the right answer, and it's definitely not the right answer for someone who is clearly new to programming and Delphi (which is apparent from the question and code posted).